# The creation of swap space in partition #3 of SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda) failed

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, swap

I am trying to install Ubuntu version 16.04.2 LTS onto my computer. My computer has a 3TB HDD which has been formatted and is brand new. I realise that this is a common question, but none of the other answers seem to work for me. If you could please help me, that would be great.

The message reads -

```
| The creation of swap space in partition #3 of SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda) failed |
```

Yes, the drive is fresh and clean, I haven't formatted it, I assumed it was pre-formatted since I bought it earlier today. I have no idea what a GPT partition table, and I tried to manually partition the drive, and the same result occurred. I am not going to dual boot, or am not planning to in the future

Comment: I assume that this is a fresh clean empty 3TB drive, yes? How did you format it? Did you lay down a fresh GPT partition table? Did you manually partition the drive, or let the Ubuntu installer do it? Are you going to dual-boot?

Comment: Yes, the drive is fresh and clean, I haven't formatted it, I assumed it was pre-formatted since I bought it earlier today. I have no idea what a GPT partition table, and I tried to manually partition the drive, and the same result occurred. I am not going to dual boot, or am not planning to in the future.

Comment: @Akshat  if you could add the information you provided to the question, by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/917570/edit), then it might attract attention

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update #1:**

Switching the SATA drive to another SATA port on the motherboard fixed the problem and allowed the user to complete the rest of this answer.

---

To initialize the hard drive and install Ubuntu...

Boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and select "Try Ubuntu". Start `gparted` from the Unity dashboard. Assure that the correct drive is selected in the popup in the top-right corner... it probably says `/dev/sda` if this is your primary/only hard disk. **Warning: the next steps will wipe out whatever drive is selected!** Go to the `Device` menu and choose `Create Partition Table...`. Choose to lay down a GPT/GUID partition table. Then click the `Apply` icon. This will leave the hard disk initialized, with 100% unallocated space. Quit `gparted`.

Now double-click on the `Install Ubuntu` icon that's on the desktop. Proceed with the installation. From there, you can manually adjust/create the partitions required... or better yet, let the installer choose the correct sizes for you.

Comment: I followed the steps as you said, and I still got the same error message as before.

Comment: @Akshat tell me **exactly** what you did. You create a GPT/GUID partition table, yes? Did you manually try to create partitions, or let the installer do it?

Comment: I booted to Ubuntu Live and opened the GParted partition application. I made sure that the drive on the top right was my 3 TB HDD. I hovered over the device menu and clicked on create the partition table, and clicked GPT partition table. I clicked apply and quit GParted after clicking apply. I went through the installation guide and I let the installer choose the sizes.

Comment: I wonder if your motherboard/SATA port has a limitation on it, like only able to address 2GB? Check for a motherboard BIOS update. Also try to lay down a new GPT partition table again, to wipe the drive, and then immediately try to create a new 16GB Swap partition. Report back.

Comment: I have no idea how to update my bios without having an os, are you able to update the bios on ubuntu live? Could you explain to me how to lay down a new GPT partition table again, and make a 16GB swap partition.

Comment: Yes, you would probably need Windows OS to update the BIOS if required. However, you can enter the BIOS now, note what version it is, then go to the manufacturer's web site with the model #, and check for new BIOS updates. To try my last test, do the first paragraph of my answer again. Then right-click on the unallocated space in the bottom pane and choose NEW and create a new 16GB swap partition, and then click the Apply icon. If we can't even do that, we have a bigger problem.

Comment: Should I update the motherboard before doing this?

Comment: I tried to add the swap partition, but it says there was No partition table found on the device.

Comment: Ah ha! That's exactly what I've been trying to fix! I'm doing this from memory right now... when you go to the Device menu and choose to create a new partition table, and you select GPT/GUID, then you must click OK, yes? Does it say anything at that point, or do you have to click on the green Apply icon to actually apply that command? I think that's the step that's missing.

Comment: I don't see that step anywhere on my create a partition table on /dev/sda

Comment: When you select `Create Partition Table...` from the Device menu, doesn't a window come up that allows you to select GPT/GUID? You select GPT/GUID then you have to click OK, yes? Now you're back to the main gparted window. There's an icon there labeled `Apply`. Click it, and that will actually perform the 1 or more commands that you've queued up... and in our case, that just consists of laying down a new partition table. Later the same process for creating a 16GB test swap partition, then click Apply again.

Comment: There is no okay when I select gpt/guid from the menu, it just says Apply. When I try to create a swap space, it just says that there is no partition table, even though I did create a new partition table. Also, it doesn't say gpt/guid it just says gpt

Comment: OK, for some reason we can't write to the drive. And since we can't write a proper GPT partition table, it won't allow us to create the partitions that we want. If this is a desktop computer, you could try connecting the drive to a different SATA port and try again. Or maybe you've just got a defective hard drive? One last thought... in your BIOS, do you have to select the drive on that SATA port?

Comment: I doubt that the drive is defective, I got the drive 2 days ago brand new.

Comment: Check the BIOS for a setting to select the drive on a specific SATA port, or an option to set it to IDE/ACHI/RAID.

Comment: I changed the sata port on my motherboard, and it let me make a partition!

Comment: Good! Still look at the BIOS for the settings that I wanted you to look at.

Comment: Thanks! Changing the SATA port on my motherboard allowed me to fully go through the installation!

Comment: Please remember to vote **and** accept my answer, and all of this dialog, if it all was helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error recently and found no answer works for me.

What I was trying to do is load the image into external hard drive (I want to install the system into it) then boot from the external hard drive and going to install. As the result I got this error message. It is most likely the installer cannot format the external disk (because it was using, I cannot format the file system, otherwise the system will crash)

The solution for me is to load the image into a USB and then boot from it, install the system into my external hard drive.

Hope this solution works for someone like me.